# 2D object transform.localPosition Lerp is sending objects to the center of their parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to have an object in my 2D game move downwards slightly using

```
startPos = new Vector2 (transform.localPosition.x, transform.localPosition.y);
lowerPos = new Vector2 (transform.localPosition.x, transform.localPosition.y - 5);
transform.localPosition = Vector2.Lerp (startPos, lowerPos, 0.1f);
```

However instead of moving down it's first moving to the center of it's parent and then moving down.  I'm sure this has something to do with parenting but I'm unsure how I can get a reference to the actual objects position instead and have it just move down from it's initial location on the screen.

 I tried using .position instead of .localPosition but in that case it moved the objects to another seemingly random spot on the screen.  I also tried the coroutine below and the object did not move at all.

```
IEnumerator lowerTile(float time) {
    Image tileImage = tile.GetComponent<Image> ();
    var startOffsetMin = tileImage.rectTransform.offsetMin;
    var startOffsetMax = tileImage.rectTransform.offsetMax;
    var targetOffsetMin = new Vector2 (startOffsetMin.x, startOffsetMin.y - 50);
    var targetOffsetMax = new Vector2 (startOffsetMax.x, startOffsetMax.y - 50);

    float currentTime = 0.0f;

    do
    {
        tileImage.rectTransform.offsetMin = Vector2.Lerp (startOffsetMin , targetOffsetMin , currentTime / time);
        tileImage.rectTransform.offsetMax = Vector2.Lerp (startOffsetMax , targetOffsetMax , currentTime / time);
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    } while (currentTime <= time);

}
```

Comment: Is this 2d object in a Canvas or in the 3d world? (Put differently, in unity, do you see a Transform or a RectTransform when selecting this object?)

Comment: It is on a canvas

Comment: Does this mean I should be using rectTransform instead of transform?

Answer (score 1):

If this is in a Canvas, you need to get a `RectTransform` (you can cast the `Transform`). From there you have two parameters that define how it is placed: anchors and offsets. In your case you want to move a number of units, so you will use offset.

Try this:

```
var rectTransform = transform as RectTransform; 
var startOffsetMin = rectTransform.offsetMin;
var startOffsetMax = rectTransform.offsetMax;
var targetOffsetMin = new Vector2(startOffsetMin.x, startOffsetMin.y - 5)
var targetOffsetMax = new Vector2(startOffsetMax.x, startOffsetMax.y - 5);

rectTransform.offsetMin = Vector2.Lerp (startOffsetMin , targetOffsetMin , 0.1f);
rectTransform.offsetMax = Vector2.Lerp (startOffsetMax , targetOffsetMax , 0.1f);
```

**More about RectTransform**

In `RectTransform`, the **anchor** parameter define a rectangle **relative to the parent** in which your element will be placed.

the **offset** parameter tell how many units you offset your rectangle relative to the rectangle you defined with anchors

Comment: The object doesn't appear to move at all using this.

Comment: Since this a canvas, the offset value might be scaled by a parent canvas scaler. Can you try to put `500` or even `5000` instead of  `-5`. It should definitely move. Also by sure you call this code multiple times (in an update, or in a coroutine) to see the Lerp effect

Comment: I updated the question with my coroutine.  It still does not work

Comment: when you select this object and run your game, what are the values in the rect transform? are they changing or not at all? What do you see, still nothing moving?

Comment: Also try adding `Debug.Log (startOffsetMax + ", " +  targetOffsetMax + ", " + (currentTime / time));` in your loop and tell me what you see in the console